# Using Element on list of numbers when defining equations

Tags: equation-solving

If been looking on how to construct equations with region or domains for some variables. 
Suppose I have x and that x can only be the number 1,2,4 or 7
The equation 2 x < 10 will then results in x being 1,2 or 4
Normally I use something like

```
xrange = (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 7)
Solve[2 x < 10 && xrange, {x}]
```

But for larger ranges and more variables it get complicated. You can build it with using strings and then use `ToExpression` of course.

Is it possible however to use something like

```
Solve[2 x < 10, x \[Element] {1, 2, 4, 7}, {x}]
```

Just wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

Re your comment to kglr's answer: "Yes but it reads not as nice I think"

```
lst = {1, 2, 4, 7};

reg = ImplicitRegion[Or @@ Thread[x == lst], x];

ineq = 2 x < 10;
```

This provides a clean `Solve` statement.

```
sol = Solve[ineq, x \[Element] reg]

(* {{x -> {1}}, {x -> {2}}, {x -> {4}}} *)
```

However, note that each solution has an extraneous `List` bracket. This precludes straightforward use of the results. For example,

```
ineq /. sol

(* {{2} < 10, {4} < 10, {8} < 10} *)
```

Consequently, to readily use the results you would have to strip out the undesired `List` brackets.

```
sol2 = Solve[ineq, x \[Element] reg] /. 
  (z_Symbol -> {val_}) :> (z -> val)

(* {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 4}} *)

ineq /. sol2

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

While the basic `Solve` is cleaner, the extra overhead before and after the `Solve` is not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point) region:

```
Solve[2 x < 10, {x} ∈ Point[List /@ lst]]
```

> {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {1, 2, 4, 7};
Solve[{2 x < 10, Or @@ Thread[x == lst]}, x]
```

> {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 4}}

Comment: Yes but it reads not as nice I think... But I think there's no alternative to build up a list of possibilities right?

Comment: @Lou, afaik we cannot use `Element[x, lst]` .

Comment: that is a pity It works on Integers, Reals etc but not on self defined sets. Will call Stephen to get this fixed :)